# If Saitama met Tatsumaki, who would win?

Tags: one-punch-man

Clearly Tatsumaki was stronger than Genos because she threw him to the wall with no struggle. If she wants, she can just send Saitama to the sun and kill him. She can also control meteors.

If Saitama meets Tatsumaki, who would win?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "who would win" hypothetical type of question. This site is focused on providing definitive answers based on facts, and not speculation. This is also a Questions and Answers site, and not a discussion forum. You could post a discussion on MyAnimeList forums or similar.

Comment: @Hakase While the manga and anime cannot answer this question, the webcomic actually can (sort of).

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question, because this question does admit a reasonable answer using canonical sources, as I indicate in my previous comment (and answer).

Comment: If you saw onepunch man (one) they fought

Answer (score 14):

In the anime and manga we cannot answer this question, as the two have never actually faced off.  However, a confrontation has occurred in the webcomic<sup>*</sup>.

> You can "watch" the entire (translated) confrontation on YouTube, in fact:
>  [Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sb0Cse_ULEM) 
>  [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BP3gkfLc1Q)

The basic rundown is as follows:

> Not long after the Garou situation, Tatsumaki aggressively confronts Fubuki when Fubuki tries to obtain further information from the Monster Association's leader (Tatsumaki simply wants her dead).  Saitama intervenes when it gets a bit serious, grabbing Tatsumaki's hand to stop her.  Tatsumaki aggressively tries to blast him away.  It fails and he doesn't let go.  She tries to bend his very energy to take him out.  It fails to do much of anything.  She tries to knock him loose, dragging him halfway across (and along) the countryside with telekinetic flight, but fails.  At one point she opens a large chasm in the earth and lets Saitama fall into it, then reseals it and buries him there.  He effortlessly digs his way up like a land shark.  At another point, she tries to lift Saitama up telekinetically, to hurl him into space, only to find it takes extreme effort to lift him even a foot off the ground.  Saitama enjoys the experience of "flying".  Ultimately Tatsumaki concedes that Saitama is extremely strong, and is aggravated with how he "hides" his true power.  However, she insists that if she were at full power—she has already resumed bleeding heavily from her head from the injuries she suffered during the Garou arc, and is possibly concussed—then she would have "easily" crushed Saitama.  Saitama seems...unconvinced.

---

*Since some people seem unaware of this, One Punch man originated as a [webcomic](http://galaxyheavyblow.web.fc2.com) (chapter links are at the bottom).  It is the fundamental canon of the story, from which the manga and anime are derived.

Comment: Is this webcomic you're citing canon or is it fanmade?

Comment: @Hakase It is *the* canon.  It is the original.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty easy question, if you're actively looking at what the MC is being portrayed as. He can't lose.

Since the comedy aspect of the series is about OPM being able to use a single punch to defeat all of his opponents, if he uses more than one punch or worse, if he loses, then the series would fall apart. He is a joke character, designed to be as over-powered as possible.

If you start to apply some physics on Tatsumaki's powers then picking someone up and throwing them at a wall is a very easy task, since when you're up in the air, you don't have any footing to exert force onto in order to move in any particular direction. Very much like when you're in a space station. Now with Genos, one can argue he could use his rockets to propel himself, which is true but we can just assume that Tatsumaki's powers are just stronger. Strong enough to hold him in place, or in this case, send him into a certain direction.

Now how will this apply to OPM? Nothing. If he gets thrown into the Sun, he'll just walk back out of it. If he gets held in place, then he'll just, I don't know, *blow* wind so strong he wipes out half a city or something. Even if he gets consumed by a black hole, he'll just punch his way out of it.

The very fundamentals of the show is that OPM can't lose. He's OPM. If he loses, then they might as well end the series right there.

Comment: As I explained in the comment to the question, it wouldn't make much sense to explain the basics of what it means to be the main character and how plot armor works in every "who would win" question for every existing title. I'm not saying this kind of speculation/discussion/theorizing is bad, but it's not a good fit for a questions and answers site. By all means, take this to a forum where such posts are a primary focus.

Comment: @Hakase  It has little to do with Saitima just happening to be the MC.  Being unable to lose practically is *his thing*  So far, it's an unspoken rule of the series that Saitama can't even be challenged let alone lose.  In an Identical manga where Tats was the main character, Saitama should still win.

Answer (score 0):

What you said about Tatsumaki sending him to the sun in the webcomic it says about how he is to heavy also in the webcomic Tasumaki attacks him constantly while Saitama doesn't fight back and Tatsumaki ends up getting tired from overdoing herself and if Saitama fought back he would win.